# my post / need is about IPA?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using xcode 7, Actually my question is how is an `IPA` created for production purposes. And what does that .ipa file is used for our xcode project. I am confused about this IPA. I have googled but cant identify the correct use of this .ipa file.

1. How to create a IPA file for production purpose?
2. What the use of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPAs are created through the Archive option on the Product menu.  The IPA is what you submit to Apple for the App Store, or make available for adhoc installs.

If you haven't changed your build scheme, the Archive option will build production-ready IPAs, in that the binaries will not have debug information included, and optimizations will be enabled.

Comment: it is important to create ipa file for submitting our app to app store or please i liitle bit confuse about this

Comment: is ther any way that ipa file will create automatically or mannual

Comment: It is never created automatically.  You create it via the Product menu, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: yes via archive option to create ipa file ok. by creating that ipa file what is use of that. please i am new to ios. haven't submit any app to app store. so only having this doubt

Comment: or while submitting to app store my project will go to app store in .ipa format???

Comment: You don't need to do anything with the ipa.  When you are ready to submit, you archive and then from the Organizer window (which opens automatically after a successful archive) you can submit to the App Store.  Until then, don't worry about it.

Comment: ok can you explaain what you said in this line`If you haven't changed your build scheme, the Archive option will build production-ready IPAs, in that the binaries will not have debug information included, and optimizations will be enabled.`

Comment: What's confusing?  You would know if you edited the scheme.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, you haven't done it.